# Wrong result of addition of two numbers in Android studio

Tags: java, android, textview

I am developing a brain trainer application for Android users. Problem is that sometimes I got the wrong result when I try to add two numbers together (as an example: question is 2 + 2 and when I press the button and displaying the result is wrong.) but it occurs randomly. Appreciate if someone could assist me to correct way. Thanks.

**This is MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button button, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    TextView sumTextView, resultTextView, pointTextView, timerTextView;
    ArrayList<Integer> answers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int locOfCorrectAns, score=0, noOfQues=0;

    public void playAgain(View view) {
        score=0;
        noOfQues=0;
        pointTextView.setText("0/0");
        resultTextView.setText("");
        timerTextView.setText("30s");
        button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                  
        generateQues();

        new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l){
                timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(l/1000)+"s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                timerTextView.setText("0s");
                resultTextView.setText(Integer.toString(score)+"/"+Integer.toString(noOfQues));
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void generateQues(){

        Random random=new Random();
        int a=random.nextInt(21);
        int b=random.nextInt(21);
        sumTextView.setText(Integer.toString(a)+"+"+Integer.toString(b));             
        locOfCorrectAns=random.nextInt(4);    
        answers.clear();            
        int incorrectAns;

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){

            if ((i == locOfCorrectAns)){
                answers.add(a + b);
            }
            else{
                incorrectAns=random.nextInt(41);

                while (incorrectAns == a + b){
                    incorrectAns=random.nextInt(41);
                }
                answers.add(incorrectAns);
            }
        }

        button1.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
        button2.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
        button3.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
        button4.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));               
    }

    public void chooseAns(View view){

        if (view.getTag().toString().equals(Integer.toString(locOfCorrectAns))){
            score++;
            resultTextView.setText("Correct!");
        }
        else{
             resultTextView.setText("Wrong!");
        }
        noOfQues++;
        pointTextView.setText(Integer.toString(score)+"/"+Integer.toString(noOfQues));
        generateQues();
    }

    public void go(View view){

        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playAgain(findViewById(R.id.playAgain));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        sumTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sumTextView) ;
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
        resultTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        pointTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);
        timerTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the wrong `tag`s for the buttons. The tags should be `0` to `3` for `button1` to `button4`.

Comment: This has increased my problem ,now for every question I am getting a wrong answer

Comment: My false, you are comparing to the `locOfCorrectAns`, then you should check your andorid:tag in your xml, see my edited answer.

Comment: I have already checked that .I don't find any problem in that ,for most of the questions ,i am getting a correct answer but for some i am not.

Comment: No, your tag for `button3` is 3 which should be 2

Comment: yes , you are right.Thank you so much.You have showed that even without being rude like others you can help.